# Moving a file with a specific string in the filename

Tags: php, file, search, move

I have a series of pdfs that contain an Id in the filename. I also have an excel file which I am able to read and get ids from.
I want to loop through all ids in the file and move any pdf that includes one of the ids in the filename to another folder.

```
$file = fopen($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'],"r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 15000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   //need something that does it here
}
```

Comment: An excel file or a CSV file? What's the format? And, most importantly... what's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Its a csv and the Pdfs all have the Id at the end. My problem is not being able to read each pdfs filename to compare it to the Id I have.

Comment: You still haven't shown us the format. What does a row in the CSV look like? What do the PDF filenames look like? Create an array of IDs from both sources and perform an intersection. Loop through the result and `rename` stuff.

Comment: Check the `glob` I've mentioned in the answer and its manual. There are many examples of  how to get the names of files in a folder

Comment: ive managed to solve it. I knew what the first part of the filename was so i wrote

$file = fopen($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'],"r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 15000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   if(file_exists('C:/windows/temp/input/string_' . $data[0])){
  rename('C:/windows/temp/input/string_' . $data[0], 'C:/windows/temp/output/string_' . $data[0]);
 }
}

Comment: You never mentioned you knew the exact structure of the file name. The  method I've mentioned can be used if you dint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to move a file. To check if it exists or not you can use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). Get the `ID`, append `.pdf` to it and check it if there.

**You need to give the path to the file, when checking and moving**

This is if Id is the file name.. ie your file name is "id.pdf".

To check for a id in the filename (similar to pattern matching), use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get all files in the directory with `.pdf`, then check if it exists using `foreach` and `preg_match`

Comment: I think it's the extraction of IDs from "an excel file" that's the issue here.

Comment: Oh.. the title and code kinda confused me..